# What is the better way to create a table editor on a webpage?

Tags: javascript, html, plugins, richtextbox

I need to create a table editor on my website where i can add new rows but define a limited number of columns (for instance 2 columns) and a richtextbox for formatting my cells (Bold, Italic, fontsize).

There is anything like [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com)? or a js plugin that you know?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried a basic Google search? A quick search for 'excel js' quickly returns promising links like [this](http://handsontable.com/).

Comment: No, it is embarrassing but i never google it 'excel js'. :P Handsontable is a good suggestion. Thanks a lot for this suggestion, Cezary.